# AlertDialog.Builder dismiss not working in API 17 android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Builder. I want to perform some action when it dismiss or cancel. So i have used `setOnDismissListener` and `setOnCancelListener` like below code. But both this method not detecting when dismissing `AlertDialog.Builder`.

```
   private static void openOptionDialog(final Context context, Item[] items, String title, DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClick) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
                context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                Item item = getItem(position);
                textView.setText(item.string);
                textView.setTextSize(16f);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.icon, 0, 0, 0);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(BDevice.getPixelFromDp(context, 15));
                return view;
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = AlertUtils.getBuilder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, positiveClick);
        builder.create().show();

        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                WidgetSettings preference = new WidgetSettings(context);
                if(preference.canWidgetTooteets()){
                    preference.clear();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                WidgetSettings preference = new WidgetSettings(context);
                if(preference.canWidgetTooteets()){
                    preference.clear();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Where `getBuilder` method in `AlertUtils` as follows,

```
public static AlertDialog.Builder getBuilder(Context context) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Dialog);
    }
```

Could you please suggest me to find a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: U want to use Aleart or perform action on aleart button like Dismis or ok?

Comment: @RavishSharma I want to perform some action when dismissing AlertDialog.Builder.

Comment: @Sangeetha Try with *AlertDialog* only instead of *AlertDialog.Builder* and add the *setOnDismissListener* in that it will work.

Comment: @jaydroider okay i will check and let you know

Comment: @jaydroider Thanks a lot. you have saved my time. I have tried with AlertDialog. Now dismiss and cancel listener are working.

Comment: @Sangeetha I am adding this as an answer accept and up-vote so it will be helpful to others also. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with *AlertDialog* only instead of *AlertDialog.Builder* and add the *setOnDismissListener* in that it will work.

**For e.g.**

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setOnDismissListener(yourDismissListener);
alert.show();

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setOnCancelListener(yourCancelListener);
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert.cancel()` instead of `alert.dismiss()` and add `OnCancelListener` like this:

```
builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```